# Use Split in SSRS Expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I've value like `100 - XYZ` in dropdown list of SSRS Report.

I want to show only `XYZ` in one of the Textbox.

I've used Split function like below,

[image]

```
=IIF(Parameters!Name.Value <> "",
 "For Name" + Replace(Split(Parameters!Name.Value, "-").GetValue(1)," ", ""),
 "For All Names")
```

Above example works fine, but when it goes to else case it always throwing error.

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this expression? Or anything wrong with my expression? Especially it is showing red line below `(1)` but as I said before it is working fine.

**Note:** *I have also tried `.GetValue(1)` recently but no success.*

Comment: Can this be a multi-select, and if so, which value of the multi-select are you trying to display in the textbox?  All of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jonnus has mentioned in comment,

> It might be showing the error as there is a problem elsewhere in the `expression`, not just the `False` part. **SSRS evaluates the entire
>   expression before executing it**, so if there is a problem anywhere it
>   will throw `#Error`

I found the alternate solution to achieve my expected result.

```
=IIF(Parameters!Name.Label = "All",
"For All Names",
"For Name " + Replace(Right(Parameters!Name.Label,
Len(Parameters!Name.Label) - InStr(Parameters!Name.Label, "-"))," ",""))
```

I tried so many times with `Split` but I always got failed. If someone has idea to solve this with `Split` then it would be great. Please share your view. Thanks Jonnus for your quick response.

Comment: With `Right` function, you should use `InStrRev` like this `=Right(Parameters!Name.Label, InStrRev(Parameters!Name.Label, "-"))`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to retrieve all the characters after the `-` in the original string.  Rather than doing a SPLIT it would be easier to understand and maintain if you used RIGHT as follows

```
=iif(Parameters!Name.Value <> "",
 "For Name " & Right(Parameters!Name.Value, 
                     Instr(Parameters!Name.Value, " - ") -1),
 "For All Names")
```

Comment: I tried above code also, but it is still throwing error in else condition. So instead of display `For All Names` it is showing `#Error` - BTW `100 - XYZ` is my Label value. So I need to use `.Label` instead of `.Value`. Also can't we achieve thru split?

Comment: It might be showing the error as there is a problem elsewhere in the expression, not just the false part.  SSRS evaluates the entire expression before executing it, so if there is a problem anywhere it will throw `#Error`.  Have you tried breaking your expression down to where exactly the problem is occurring (i.e. just the true part, just the `Right`, just the `instr`)?

Comment: yes, I've break my expression. it is working if I remove `Replace(Split(Parameters!Name.Value, "-").GetValue(1)," ", "")` but I'm not getting why it is causing a problem? Also I read your above comment so now I came to know that I must have to check entire expression. - I found one alternate solution will post soon if we cannot solve with Split. :( - If you have any idea to do with split then please share... else I will play with `Right` `Len` and `InStr` to fix.